# Make A javascript variable only avaliable to functions on the same .js file

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, local-variables

I somewhat new to Javascript and I'm stuck on this one item. Can someone please show me how to make a javascript variable only usable on the .js file that it is on.

EXAMPLE:

Say I have two .js files, PG1 & PG2.
PG1 contains var channel = Channel01;

PG2 contains a variable with the same name, but a different entered Variable
(the part after the equals sign) (var channel = Channel02)

I don't want function1 on PG1 to use the variable on PG2 or for function2 on PG2 to use the variable on PG1.

I am also calling these functions from a seperate HTML page.

Problem: All of my functions end up using only one variable no matter what page they are on.
(ex. function1 & function2 both use var channel = channel01)

Question: How can I limit functions on page1 to use only the variables on that .js page

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

module pattern :

```
var myModule = (function(exports){

    var x = "foo";

    exports.myFunction = function(){
        alert(x);
    };

})(typeof exports!="undefined" && exports instanceof Object ? exports : window );
```

`myFunction` will be available in the `window` scope in the browser.

**EDIT**

i quote the author : "I am also calling these functions from a seperate HTML page."

so the author needs a global access to the functions he defines.

var myModule is not needed though , nor export , it is just for AMD compatibility :

```
(function(exports){

    var x = "foo";

    exports.myFunction = function(){
        alert(x);
    };

})(window);
```

now x for myFunction only exists in the closure , but myFunction can still access x in the global scope. any x definition in the global scope or whatever scope will not affect `x = "foo"`

Comment: true but you can choose what's global and what's not , and furthermore the author needs to call some functions outside the file.

Comment: as i just wrote , the author needs to call some functions outside the the the  file they are declared. but myFunction will remember where it was created.

Comment: @Eli , if in the global scope you do var x = 3 , myFunction will still alert foo ,

Comment: @Eli , ok , i could ditch myModule it would be the same , the issue is not my module , the issue is about functions using "private variables" that are defined in closures , therefore nothing but them can access inner variables. you could redefine myModule it would not matter. x = foo would still exist. Try to overwrite myModule and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks Camus for you answer:) I tried the syntax you responded with, but I can't figure out how to call myFunction. I tried using this: <script language="javascript">exports.myFunction()</script>.

Comment: just write : myFunction() and it should work. window is the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for your Help!:) I did what you said and it works great!

Answer (score 9):

Wrap the whole thing in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression, which will effectively give the file its own *scope*.

```
(function() {
   // Your file's contents live here.
})();
```

Comment: Thank you to all who answered!:) I found that the first answer worked the best, but I do have one more question. How would I call one of my functions that is nested inside the invoked function expression.(ex. on my html page I want to call function 1 that is nested in the invoked function.) Thanks again

Comment: @user1402171 You'd need to explicitly expose those functions to a scope that your document can access, e.g. `window`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't actually need to expose any of your variables to the global scope, you can wrap your entire JavaScript code in an immediately-invoked function expression or IIFE. Here, you define an anonymous function expression and immediately invoke it. The result is that instead of polluting the global scope with your variables, you keep them nice and tidy in the local scope of that function.

```
(function() {
    var channel = Channel01;

    // Put the rest of your PG1 code here, for example:

    function init() {
        channel.open();
    }

    init();
})();
```

You can then wrap your PG2 code in an IIFE in a similar fashion. The result will be that the two scripts share no variables other than the already defined global variables, such as `Channel01` and `Channel02`.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a direct answer to your question, this is related and important, as missing it out could pollute other modules. If you dont use the var keyword the variable is on the global scope i.e

```
(function () {
   x = 'foo'; //x is on the global scope and can be seen everywhere
})()

(function () {
   var y = 'bar'; //y is local to this function
})()
```

I hope i havent duplicated what anyone has said above but i couldnt see it mentioned