# Javascript - two objects which appear to be identical but aren't

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS comparative newbie... spent about 3 hours on this so far... Please consider this code if you'd be so kind:

```
function updateDataFields( mapIDToNewValue )
{
    $.each(dataFields, function(key, value)
    {
        var dataField = $( value );
        // var dataField = $(this); // same difference
        console.log( dataField );
        var iD = dataField.attr('id');

        //  DOES NOT WORK!!! i.e. going val() on this object does not update the INPUT element on the page!
        // dataField.val(mapIDToNewValue[ iD ]);

        var thePageElement = $( '#' + iD );
        console.log( thePageElement );
        console.log( '£ is dataField the same object as thePageElement?' + ( dataField === thePageElement ? 'yes' : 'no, you fool' ));
        // DOES WORK:
        thePageElement.val( mapIDToNewValue[ iD ] );

    });
}
```

Explanation: `dataFields`, a file-global variable*, is passed by an outside script which calls this one, using a (fully) global variable which attaches `dataFields` to itself in piggyback fashion.  This data structure, `dataFields`, consists of all the page elements with the class `.dataField`.  All of these are in fact `INPUT` HTML elements.

Using the supplied param `mapIDToNewValue` (from an AJAX call to a dbase), I want to update the respective contents (i.e. text) of these `INPUT`s.  `mapIDToNewValue` is a map in which the key is the same as the `attr( 'id' )` of these `dataFields`, and the value is the new value which needs to be displayed in the `INPUT`.

It turns out that `thePageElement` is ***not*** the same object as `dataField`.  When I  examine the console output for them both they appear virtually the same... except that `dataField`, for example, has 0 `height`, which is enough to chill the soul!

My working hypothesis is that somehow `dataFields`, when passed from the calling script via this piggyback global variable, somehow turned its contents into "phantom" objects: they have the same `id` as `thePageElement`... but are incapable of having any effect on the real page elements themselves!

NB there is no possibility of duplicate ids here, or anything like that.

Any explanation welcome!

* implemented using anonymous function as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10644970/595305).

***later, in response to Patrick Barr's comment:***

It's quite involved. Given your use of the word "interesting", I was moved to find out what your rep might be. If you had been a proven JS guru (you may nonetheless be one of course) I'd have been inclined to think that I need to embark on a forensic fault-finding mission.

The context: I'm developing a sort of "MSAccess Forms for MySQL front end" type of a thing, which is sorely lacking out there IMHO. At the moment I'm tackling subforms, and a major aim is to re-use code as much as is humanly possible. I'm rapidly getting out of my depth, not least because of the asynchronicity/concurrency issues that spring up, gorgon-like, at every turn. I'm thinking about how to answer your question in an informative, useful way.

To anyone else: I now realise I have to strip down my project to the bare bones to find out what's going on here... and if still baffled post an SSCCE (as we call it in Java) ... just thought initially that an expert out there might recognise a well-known issue and be able to set me straight.

Comment: `dataFields` is not defined in your function

Comment: @johnSmith he explained that dataFields is a file-global variable

Comment: `dataFields` is a file-global variable... it was passed to this script when the script was first called.

Comment: interesting, could you provide how you populate `dataFields`? from what I can tell the provided code should work, so perhaps there's something more going on?

Comment: can you paste the console output for  `console.log( dataField );`

Comment: Your last `console.log` line has incorrect number of single quotes??

Comment: @JonBrave tx... typo, not in the code, now updated.

Comment: @KaushalNiraula: not sure how I do that with the FF inspector... googling now to find out

Comment: This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/vjo8d9vy/ We really need to know how you populate `dataFields`. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for going to the trouble... but of course in this jsfiddle you are not passing an Array of objects from one script to another.

Comment: @mikerodent And that matters how?

Comment: Generally, two variables containing objects, unless assigned to the exact same object, will not be equal to each other. You'll need a way of comparing the objects by a primitive value.

Comment: @ChrisG I can't answer that, as a comparative newbie... I haven't got a clue why that wouldn't be the same thing... as I said in my last edit I now intend to strip things back to the bare bones and examine the thing forensically...

Comment: Sorry, but have you said _anywhere_ whether you get output `yes` or `no, you fool`?  Or are we supposed to guess?

Comment: "no, you fool"...!

Comment: I can reproduce the issue like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qg07abfr/ And just for reference, `$("body") !== $("body")`

Comment: @ChrisG wow that is very kind of you to go such lengths. So as a comparative newbie I'm assuming now that somehow I'm detaching my nodes from the document.body ... a great clue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having examined things here I now understand what happened (to a degree).

In fact the `dataFields` `Array` was obtained from the result of an AJAX call which loaded (or more accurately *returned*, as the `data` param in the callback function) an HTML fragment, containing several page elements with class `.dataField`, which I then gathered by going `data.find( '.dataField' )`.

But in fact these "page elements", despite having hundreds of properties, just like objects directly "mapping" to page elements, were indeed "phantom" objects: specifically, properties such as `clientHeight` were 0, seemingly an indication that this is a non-visible object.

It was only when the HTML returned in the AJAX callback was inserted into the `document` structure (and made visible by setting `hidden` to `false` for the encompassing `DIV`) that this HTML generated real page elements.  I then had to select these page elements with class `.dataField` to get hold of the non-phantom objects (having `clientHeight` 20 or whatever).

Quite strange, as these initial "phantom" objects did NOT become "real" objects as a consequence of the HTML being added to the `document`.  They remained ... useless (and confusing!).